# FFmpeg Encode Script Improvements

Tags: ffmpeg

Im using a ffpmeg script to encode videos into multiple mp4 qualities, This is only a basic script, need suggestion for how to improve speed and performance.

```
# encoding: utf-8
# coder:    Ishaq Khan
# version:  1.0

import os
import subprocess
import sys
import time
import re
import datetime

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])))

print()
print('*' * 34)
print('** Real-time Video Encoder v1.0 **')
print('*' * 34)
print()

paths = {
    "src_dir" : "/www/wwwroot/videos/mp4/source",
    "out_dir" : "/www/wwwroot/videos/mp4/pinoy"
}

src_dir = paths['src_dir']
out_dir = paths['out_dir']

if not os.path.exists(src_dir):
    print('Source directory specified in "paths" dictionary is not valid.')
    exit()

elif not os.path.exists(out_dir):
    print('Output directory specified in "paths" dictionary is not valid.')
    exit()

# --------------------------------------------------------------------

last_act = 'encoding'

while True:
    if last_act == 'encoding':
        print('Watching source folder for incoming video files...')

    last_act = 'waiting'

    cur_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    cur_yr = str(cur_date.year)
    cur_mon = str(cur_date.month).zfill(2)
    cur_day = str(cur_date.day).zfill(2)

    src_files = os.listdir(src_dir)
    src_files = [eve for eve in src_files if eve.lower().endswith('.mp4')]
    src_files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getctime(src_dir + '/' + x))

    if src_files:
        src_file = src_files[0]
        print('Processing "{}"'.format(src_file))

        dest_dir = '{}/{}/{}/{}/{}'.format(out_dir, cur_yr, cur_mon, cur_day, src_file.rsplit('.', 1)[0])
        os.makedirs(dest_dir, exist_ok=True)

        ffmpeg_com = 'ffmpeg -y -loglevel error -i "{}/{}" -i watermark_360p.png -filter_complex "scale=640:360,overlay=0:0" -codec:a copy "{}/360.mp4"'.format(src_dir, src_file, dest_dir)
        subprocess.call(ffmpeg_com, shell=True)
        ffmpeg_wm_com = 'ffmpeg -y -loglevel error -ss 0:0:10 -i "{}/360.mp4" -vframes 1 -q:v 2 "{}/poster.jpg"'.format(dest_dir, dest_dir)
        subprocess.call(ffmpeg_wm_com, shell=True)

        ffprobe_com = 'ffprobe -loglevel error -i "{}/{}" -show_streams'.format(src_dir, src_file)
        ffprobe_com_out = subprocess.check_output(ffprobe_com, shell=True).decode('utf-8')
        height = re.search('(?<=\nheight=)\d+', ffprobe_com_out)
        height = int(ffprobe_com_out[height.start():height.end()])

        if height >= 720:
            ffmpeg_com = 'ffmpeg -y -loglevel error -i "{}/{}" -i watermark_720p.png -filter_complex "scale=1280:720,overlay=0:0" -codec:a copy "{}/720.mp4"'.format(
                src_dir, src_file, dest_dir)
            subprocess.call(ffmpeg_com, shell=True)
            ffmpeg_wm_com = 'ffmpeg -y -loglevel error -ss 0:0:10 -i "{}/720.mp4" -vframes 1 -q:v 2 "{}/poster.jpg"'.format(
                dest_dir, dest_dir)
            subprocess.call(ffmpeg_wm_com, shell=True)

        os.remove(src_dir + '/' + src_file)

        last_act = 'encoding'

    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Your question is about programming, it better fit Stack Overflow site, and not Super User. In fact, your question doesn't fit any of the Stack Exchange community sites, because it is to general... Try building a minimal code sample that is well defined. Explain the problem in words. Asking a good questions requires a lot of effort (you can't just post your code and ask for suggestions).

Comment: Note that there is a ffmpeg python module. no need to use subprocess